# How do I completely remove openSUSE secure boot?

Tags: grub2, uefi, boot-loader, bios

I was using a dual boot of openSUSE and Windows and I decided to delete OpenSUSE by deleting the partition. On rebooting, I found out that the secure boot for openSUSE was still there, leading to an error. to make things worse, the Windows boot loader was no longer there and I have to access it through the UEFI settings. How do I change this to automatically boot windows again?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change booting order. Follow the instruction to change booting order given in your BIOS. Ususally, it is something like F5 to move upward in the list and F6 to put in lower position.

Comment: Windows has disappeared from the booting order. That's why I have to access it from the  UEFI settings in the startup menu.

Comment: If windows disappear from booting order, how you can access it from UEFI settings ?

Comment: I have told you to change the order in the UEFI settings.

Comment: Also [read](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150814/how-to-remove-ubuntu-from-efi-partition#1150821)